# How to get a Multipolygon object from Overpass QL?

Tags: python, shapely, overpass-api, geopandas

I'm new to OSM/Overpass QL and there's a simple problem that I can't solve. I've been able to figure out the a query that will return the maritime boundary of a country. For example:

```
(rel[boundary="administrative"][name="Puerto Rico"][admin_level="4"];>;);way(r);(._;>;);out;
```

This returns the boundary as a set of ways. Using `overpy` I've been able to get the returned ways and display them using shapely/matplotlib, and I'm confident they have the data I need.

What I can't figure out is how can I reliably convert the returned set of ways to a MultiPolygon object, ideally a `shapely.geometry.MyltiPolygon`.

The above query is only an example that produces a fairly simple set of `ways`, but there are other queries that return much more complex results, such as

```
(rel[boundary="administrative"]["name:en"="French Polynesia"][admin_level="3"];>;);way(r);(._;>;);out;
```

I understand that Overpass doesn't handle (multi)polygons, but I assume there must be a simple way to achieve this using python/GeoPandas.shapely. I've tried some manual approaches, but they are error-prone and I'd be extremely surprised if there are no implemented librariessolutions to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Extracting such amounts of data makes only sense if you run your own Overpass instance! For coastlines you should take a look at http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coast

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mmd. I agree that's a lot of data if you do the whole world, but if you only care about a few countries, I think is a valid approach. That said, thanks for the reference to the coast data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using the function `ways2poly` function I wrote in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jorgehatccrma/799ad3411293fd76add6a3230ee65640).

I also added code to run the Overpass queries (using [`overpy`](http://python-overpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), in case anyone needs it.

Answer (score 3):

I convert OSM ways to polygons using Shapely's `linemerge`, `unary_union`, and `polygonize`.

Like so:

```
import overpass
import shapely.geometry as geometry
from shapely.ops import linemerge, unary_union, polygonize

api = overpy.Overpass()

query = """ YOUR QUERY HERE """
response = api.query(query)

lss = [] #convert ways to linstrings

for ii_w,way in enumerate(response.ways):
    ls_coords = []

    for node in way.nodes:
        ls_coords.append((node.lon,node.lat)) # create a list of node coordinates

    lss.append(geometry.LineString(ls_coords)) # create a LineString from coords 


merged = linemerge([*lss]) # merge LineStrings
borders = unary_union(merged) # linestrings to a MultiLineString
polygons = list(polygonize(borders))
```

Running your query and plotting in matplotlib:

[image: polygon visualisation]